# php showing message sent but didn't receive it to my email

Tags: php, phpmailer, spf

So my smtp php mailer is showing that the message was successfully sent but in reality it's not. I am now using email from the same domain that Synchro suggested because I was using gmail [please have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72331805/smtp-working-good-on-hostinger-and-not-working-on-bamboozle-me-host) and had issues with it and php mailer was showing error but after switching to mail from the same domain actually it is showing sent but I am not receiving any email.
So I went to my email logs and found this.

```
Event:  failure error
User:   eightysh
Domain: eighty6.shop
From Address:   baltajiwissam@gmail.com
Sender: no-reply@eighty6.shop
Sent Time:  May 21, 2022, 9:34:09 AM
Sender Host:    www.eighty6.shop
Sender IP:  185.93.244.110
Authentication: dovecot_login
Spam Score: 
Recipient:  baltajiwissam@gmail.com
Delivery User:  -system-
Delivery Domain:    
Delivered To:   
Router: remoteserver_route
Transport:  mailchannels_smtp
Out Time:   May 21, 2022, 9:34:09 AM
ID: 1nsIgk-0000C6-Im
Delivery Host:  smtp.mailchannels.net
Delivery IP:    52.25.134.49
Size:   1.54 KB
Result: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256 CV=yes: SMTP error from remote mail server after end 
of data: 550 5.7.1 [BFD] Sender prohibited by SPF
```

i did few research about Sender prohibited by SPF but i didn't get it :/ am i suppose to add my pc ip address to the host ?? if yes its not logical cause its gonna be a public form please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you're doing, but at a guess it looks like you are sending from a gmail address without sending through a gmail server, and that will always fail SPF checks, because google doesn't allow that. It's nothing to do with the submitter's address, but the email server that you send the message through – if it's not `smtp.gmail.com`, then you can't use a gmail address as your from address.

Comment: Actually its wired that is looking like i am using gmail through another host but no i am using domain mail and using same host !!